# Python Library for Browser-Based Twitter Oauth

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I would love to find a Python library for Twitter that supports a browser-based application type, so the user can just hit "authorize" and have Twitter return them to the callback url, as opposed to copying and pasting a PIN number. I've tried just about every library, and they all rely on the PIN method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure tweepy allows the redirect method: http://code.google.com/p/tweepy/

Comment: THe only reason I know is because I was just in its OAuth code recently (looking for something else) and I saw the code for redirecting back and forth.

Comment: I don't know about that. The getAccessToken in the OauthHandler class relies upon a *user supplied" PIN number.